# How to add Grand Total to Pivot Table?

Tags: excel, sum, pivot-table

I am not able to add Grand Total in Pivot Table in the following case, even though I tried toggling in Layout Tab. Please explain how it can be done.

[image]

Comment: There are no values in `Rows areas`.

Comment: Moving "Values" to Rows area also doesn't display the Grand Total

Comment: I didn't said that you need to move the values to rows area. If there is nothing in rows area and you have only values then the grand total won't show up

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a additional column to use as the row value and the two counts must be in the values

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Could you please add a pic? I am not able to follow what do you mean by additional column.